# Anyway to avoid Swagger be affected by authorization policies in .NET 5.0?

Tags: swagger, .net-5

Every was fine with Swagger until I added an authorization policy in the StartUp Class:

```
options.AddPolicy("requiredRoleType", policy => policy.RequireRole());
```

The problem: Swagger is inaccessible because this policy. I've tried to move services.AddSwaggerGen in a different order but the problem remains.

Anyway to make Swagger bypasses authorization policies?

(using .NET 5.0 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.0.7)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using Authorization Requirements as described in the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0

In this case Swagger is not affected by Authorization Requirements.